# pandas how to assign group id to groups whose sizes are > 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a `groupby` on a `df`, and then assign each group an id, whose size is > 1;

```
df_gr = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])

df_filtered = df_gr.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

if df_filtered.shape[0] == 0:
   df_filtered['id'] = -1
else:
   # put ids in df_filtered
```

I am wondering how to do that.

```
a    b        c        d      
10   2017     20.0     231    
10   2017     20.0     223    
20   2018     10.0     113    
30   2017     11.0     134    
30   2017     11.0     112    
30   2017     11.0     111
```

the result df,

```
 a    b        c        d      id
10   2017     20.0     231     1
10   2017     20.0     223     1
30   2017     11.0     134     2
30   2017     11.0     112     2
30   2017     11.0     111     2

if df_filtered.shape[0] != 0:
   df_filtered["id"] = df_filtered.groupby(
                ['a', 'b', 'c']).grouper.group_info[0]
```

Comment: `df_filtered = df_gr.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)` does not work?

Comment: @jezrael it works, but i like to know how to get an `int` id for each group, whose sizes are > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['id'] = np.where(df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['a'].transform('size') > 1, -1, 2)
print (df)
    a     b     c    d  id
0  10  2017  20.0  231  -1
1  10  2017  20.0  223  -1
2  20  2018  10.0  113   2
3  30  2017  11.0  134  -1
4  30  2017  11.0  112  -1
5  30  2017  11.0  111  -1
```

If want `1` and `0` values another solution is cast boolean mask to `integer`s:

```
df['id'] = np.where(df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['a'].transform('size') > 1, 1, 0)
```

```
df['id'] = (df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['a'].transform('size') > 1).astype(int)
print (df)
    a     b     c    d  id
0  10  2017  20.0  231   1
1  10  2017  20.0  223   1
2  20  2018  10.0  113   0
3  30  2017  11.0  134   1
4  30  2017  11.0  112   1
5  30  2017  11.0  111   1
```

EDIT I think need [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
#create values by size of columns
df['id'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['a'] .transform('size')

#filter out rows
df = df[df['id'] > 1]
#sequencial id values
df['id'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['a'].ngroup() + 1
    a     b     c    d  id
0  10  2017  20.0  231   1
1  10  2017  20.0  223   1
3  30  2017  11.0  134   2
4  30  2017  11.0  112   2
5  30  2017  11.0  111   2
```

Comment: sry, just added a sample df, but your solution looks fine as well

Comment: in your solution, how to assign a sequencial id to group whose size > 1, like the result `df` in my op

Comment: added a possible solution to my op, what do you think

Comment: for the last solution `df['id']=[1,1,3,3,3]`